# Why Global variable redefinition is not allowed?

Tags: c, memory, global-variables, redefinition

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i =0;
i=2;

int main(){

    // some Code here
    return 0;
}
```

**Error :**  `/Users/vaibhavkumar/Documents/C/primeFactors.c|4|error: redefinition of 'i'|`

1. Why redefinition of the variable is not allowed in C.
2. Global variables are stored in Data Segment(area of memory), at the same place where static variables are stored. How came static variables can be redeclared ?

Comment: Which line is the error on? The code you're showing us now should not produce an error.

Comment: i=2; is not a valid statement outside a function.  The error message is wrong - but it is telling you that something is not right.  Why would you want to redeclare a static variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not *redefinition* it is *assignment*.

Assignment is not the same as *initialisation* in C, and cannot be done outside a function - there is no thread of execution in that context, so when would it be done?

Variables with `static` linkage are no different to global variables (with `extern` linkage) in this respect, however static linkage variables are *local* to a single compilation unit and are not visible externally.  If you declare two statics of the same name in separate compilation units, they are entirely independent and unrelated variables - they needn't even be the same type.

Note that *static linkage* is distinct from *static storage*, but they use the same keyword.  All global and static linkage variables have static storage class implicitly, but a *function local* variable declared static has *static storage class* - i.e. it always exists - like a global, but is only visible locally.

Answer (score 0):

Clifford explained the difference between assignment and initialization. But just fore completeness: You're not allowed to do assignments outside functions. Only initializations.

But why do you get this strange error? It's because of *implicit declaration*.

If we're talking about global space, then this

```
int i = 0;
i = 2;
```

is actually equivalent to this:

```
int i = 0;
int i = 2;
```

And this code will print 42:

```
#include <stdio.h>

i = 42;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

The reason is backwards compatibility. Don't use this "feature"

The logic behind the strange message that seem very unrelated, is kind of like this:

1. Implicit declarations are allowed
2. Assignments are not allowed in global space
3. Therefore, `i=2;` in global space, must be a declaration